# Save Pandas plots created in a loop into different files

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I wrote a script to graph some columns of a `pandas.DataFrame`. It is:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df=pd.read_csv('alcohol_cons_18', sep=',') #this is the loaded data
a_list=list(df.columns.values) #a list of its columns
for ielement in range(len(a_list)): #iterate over columns and make charts
    print ("column name is %s" %(a_list[ielement]))
    if a_list[ielement]!= 'age':
        df.plot(x='age', y=a_list[ielement])
        plt.savefig(a_list[ielement] + '.png') #savefigures
```

but the script saves figures in a cummulative way. So in the second figure there are the first and second graph, and so on..
Any idea how to modify the script to save those graphs in different files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does using

```
plt.close()
```

as documented [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.close.html?highlight=matplotlib%20pyplot%20close#matplotlib.pyplot.close) resolve your issue?

Otherwise, you can try assigning the plot to an enumerated figure, like so

```
for ielement in range(len(a_list)): #iterate over columns and make charts
    print ("column name is %s" %(a_list[ielement]))
    if a_list[ielement]!= 'age':
        fig = plt.figure(ielement)
        df.plot(x='age', y=a_list[ielement])
        plt.savefig(a_list[ielement] + '.png')
```

Comment: not sure about the difference in your code but plt.close() was the missing part. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Either `plt.clf()` or `plt.cla()` depending on whether you want to save certain figure parts would clear the canvas.